# Run NS-3 Simulation on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, python, c#, ns2

I need to tun this NS-3 simulation project on my ubuntu VM. Also, I need to obtain the graph related to this simulation.[mmWave-IAB](https://github.com/signetlabdei/ns3-mmwave-iab)

I don't know what are the necessary files to run. Can anybody help me???

Comment: see http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hirsute/man1/ns-3-tutorial.1.html The manual has all you need to know

Comment: @Ashan, you can also ask at "ns-3-users"  https://groups.google.com/g/ns-3-users

Comment: **mmWave Cellular Network Simulator**, installation and usage https://apps.nsnam.org/app/mmwave/